# How to automatically create filtered list from Excel dataset using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I got a problem with Excel 2007 where I cannot find a solution to. I think one has to use VBA to do it by I am pretty unexperienced with that.
I have a dataset in Excel (about 1k lines) with 10 columns. In an other tab/worksheet, I now want to display the data filtered by one column (country codes). It can be done dirty with autofiltering but it should be more like a report so it has to look good.

Let me make an example what I mean:

DATASET

Column | Column 2 | Column 3

Hans | GER | 16

Peter | US | 29

Maria | GER | 30

Darian | US | 15

Lisa | GER | 40

In an other Tab/Worksheet, I now want an automatically updated, formatted and filtered list based on this data set, e.g.:

REPORT

*Germany*

Hans | 16

Maria | 30

Lisa | 40

*US*

Peter | 29

Darian | 15

I hope you understand what I mean. If I add new lines of data in my dataset sheet, I want the report to be automatically updated (so I can't just but autofilter lists below each other because the number of rows which will be needed depends on the data points). I think this should be pretty easy to do using a VBA macro, but I have no clue how to do it... Help very much appreciated!

Thanks upfront!

*

Comment: Do you have access to MS Access?  It would be a lot better fit for custom report generation like this, which is not really Excel's strong point.  You could even link to the data as a linked table if it must come from Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip Mellamokb! Sounds good and worked. One thing about the Access Report: If I link to my Excel Sheet, it does not round the calculated numbers as it does in excel and the numbers in the report are way to long... Is there a function in Access like it is in Excel to Auto-Round the numbers after e.g. 2nd decimal?

Comment: And: As I want to learn it, I am still curious about what the solution would look like in Excel? Thanks for any hints :)

Comment: I wouldn't bother even trying in Excel.  It's one thing to make a grid report in Excel, but to use grouping headers is going to be very, very complicated and not worth the effort because it's the wrong tool.  You'll be rewriting the Access Report engine in Excel VBA.  (Unless there's some feature I don't know about)

Comment: Re: the rounding.  I think you'll need to apply a round function in the report, like `ROUND(SourceFieldName, 2)` for 2 decimal places.  Linked tables are just about getting data, so formulas and formats are not communicated to Access from Excel.

Comment: Thanks you, I managed to add the rounding function.
Back to Excel: Let's say I can hardcode the group headings as the number of countries is limited. Can I (maybe even with formulars) display the corresponding data of that group below it and automatically add any additions made in the original list? Shouldn't that work somehow if I Index the data points? Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: It is possible yes, I never said it wasn't.  I just don't see the point in even trying when Access does the job quite nicely.  You have to walk down the spreadsheet vertically, putting in the right data, then putting in the headers.  While the headers are fixed, what isn't fixed is the number of entries that belong under each header and that's where the challenging part comes in, because the headers and data lines have to be dynamically arranged.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a PivotTable combined with a dynamic named range?

Given your data set above is set up in Sheet1 of your workbook, starting in A1 with column names. See the following solution.

1) Enter a dynamic named range for your dataset, like below.

[image]

This will ensure that any new data that is added to the end, or inserted into the middle of the data set gets captured and updated automatically with a pivot table refresh.

2) Base your pivot table on the Named Range.

[image]

3) Finally, set up your PivotTable like below.

[image]

You can then format your pivot table how you like.

Comment: dynamic range works better than just a straight pivot - all you have to do is refresh the pivot table when you add more data

Comment: Problem is that in the actual data set there are non-numeric attributes and the pivot table can't display them because it is neither a SUM nor an average etc...

Comment: you can use `COUNT` against non-numeric attributes

Comment: you should look into the PT a bit more. I think you can find a solution to what you are after.

Comment: I played around with PT now but still got problems with non-numeric attributes. If I use COUNT then the attribute does not get displayed but just a "1". 
Speaking in the example from above, let's say I got a town specified in each data set and I want it to be displayed in an column in the pivot table. How can I switch here from letters to numbers? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot table can do the type of grouping you are looking for. Using the data you provided, this is what I get from a pivot table:

[image]

Comment: good solution, but this doesn't fully address the issue that the user needs to be able to update data that is added after the original PT is created. Updating the range source is time is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at pivot tables. they can be a bit complicated but once you figure out how they work they are very useful.

Comment: would have given a +1 for a good Excel solution, but in light of the same solution provided in other answers with much more user-friendly help, hard to do so. On the other, welcome to SO! Have fun on here :)